# Sliding marker in google map is giving error google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to implement sliding marker in google map. I am trying to create some dummy location and trying to use sliding marker on that but it's giving me error google not defined. I'm using normal html and cdn link for this. I have gone through some of the example in internet that trying to do this.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Simple Map</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
          /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
           * element that contains the map. */
          #map {
            height: 100%;
          }
          /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
          html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
          }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>

        var    cars = [{
                id:1,
                coords:{
                    lat:12.98643328,
                    lng:77.75361996,
                }
            },{
                id:2,
                coords:{
                    lat:12.97750789,
                    lng:77.75115929,
                }
            },{
                id:3,
                coords:{
                    lat:12.96529638,
                    lng:77.74909935,
                }
            },{
                id:4,
                coords:{
                    lat:12.95341885,
                    lng:77.74446449,
                }
            }]






          var map , marker;
          function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 8
            });
          }
          var i = 0;
          setInterval(function(){ 
              if(i === 0){
                  addMarker(cars[i].coords);

              }else{
                  updateMarker(cars[i].coords);
                  if (i === 4){
                    i = 1;
                  }
                }
           }, 3000);

           function addMarker(coords){
              i++;

                let latlong1 = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng);
                marker = new SlidingMarker({
                map : this.map,
                position: latlong1,

                });

                marker.setDuration(1000);
                marker.setEasing('linear');
           }

           function updateMarker(coords){

            let latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat,coords.lng);
            //this.map.setCenter(latlong);
            marker.setPosition(latlong);
            i++;
          }

        </script>


            <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <!-- <script  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> -->
            <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDv-h2II7DbFQkpL9pDxNRq3GWXqS5Epts&callback=initMap"
            async defer></script>
            <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marker-animate-unobtrusive/0.2.8/vendor/markerAnimate.js"></script>
            <script  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marker-animate-unobtrusive/0.2.8/SlidingMarker.min.js"></script>

        </body>
    </html>
```

I am getting this error

```
markerAnimate.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at markerAnimate.js:10
(anonymous) @ markerAnimate.js:10
SlidingMarker.js:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at SlidingMarker.js:42
    at SlidingMarker.js:13
    at SlidingMarker.js:13
(anonymous) @ SlidingMarker.js:42
(anonymous) @ SlidingMarker.js:13
(anonymous) @ SlidingMarker.js:13
liveloc.html:80 Uncaught ReferenceError: SlidingMarker is not defined
    at addMarker (liveloc.html:80)
    at liveloc.html:66
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is loading the Google Maps Javascript API v3 asynchronously.  But the `MarkerAnimate` and `SlidingMarker` libraries depend on it.

One option is to change:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

(remove the "async defer").

**code snippet:**

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var cars = [{
    id: 1,
    coords: {
      lat: 12.98643328,
      lng: 77.75361996,
    }
  }, {
    id: 2,
    coords: {
      lat: 12.97750789,
      lng: 77.75115929,
    }
  }, {
    id: 3,
    coords: {
      lat: 12.96529638,
      lng: 77.74909935,
    }
  }, {
    id: 4,
    coords: {
      lat: 12.95341885,
      lng: 77.74446449,
    }
  }]
  var map, marker;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
      },
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    if (i === 0) {
      addMarker(cars[i].coords);

    } else {
      updateMarker(cars[i].coords);
      if (i === 4) {
        i = 1;
      }
    }
  }, 3000);

  function addMarker(coords) {
    i++;

    let latlong1 = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
    marker = new SlidingMarker({
      map: this.map,
      position: latlong1,

    });

    marker.setDuration(1000);
    marker.setEasing('linear');
  }

  function updateMarker(coords) {

    let latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.lat, coords.lng);
    //this.map.setCenter(latlong);
    marker.setPosition(latlong);
    map.setCenter(latlong);
    i++;
  }
</script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDv-h2II7DbFQkpL9pDxNRq3GWXqS5Epts&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marker-animate-unobtrusive/0.2.8/vendor/markerAnimate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marker-animate-unobtrusive/0.2.8/SlidingMarker.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

addMarker function is being executed before loading of google map script. Please put setInterval in initMap function after initialization of map.